# How to make new variable across conditions

Tags: r, variables, conditional-statements

I need to calculate new variable from data using conditions. New Pheno.
Data set is huge.
I have data set: Animal, Record, Days, Pheno

```
A R D   P
1 1 240 300
1 2 230 290
2 1 305 350
2 2 260 290
3 1 350 450
```

Conditions are:

Constant pheno per day is 2.

1. If record days is more than 305 old pheno should be keept.
2. If record is less than 305 but has next records Pheno should be keept.
3. If record is less than 305 and have no next records it should be calculated as : 305-days*constant+pheno = (305 - 260)*2+300

Example for animal 1 having less than 305 for both records. So First record will be same in new pheno, but secon record is las and has less than 305, so we need to re-calculate... (305-230)*2+290=440

Finaly data will be like:

```
A R D P N_P
1 1 240 300 300
1 2 230 290 440
2 1 305 350 350
2 2 260 290 380
3 1 350 450 450
```

How to do it in R or linux ...

Comment: What exactly does "has next records" in condition 2 mean? In condition 3: Is a lactation the same as a record?

Comment: Yeah. Next record = next lactation. Sorr. Records are repeated

Comment: ok, 380, now edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution with base R

```
df <- read.table(header=TRUE, text=
"A R D   P
1 1 240 300
1 2 230 290
2 1 305 350
2 2 260 290
3 1 350 450")

newP <- function(d) {
  np <- numeric(nrow(d))
  for (i in 1:nrow(d)) {
    if (d$D[i] > 305) { np[i] <- d$P[i]; next }
    if (d$D[i] <= 305 && i<nrow(d)) { np[i] <- d$P[i]; next }
    np[i] <- (305-d$D[i])*2 + d$P[i]
  }
  d$N_P <- np
  return(d)
}

D <- split(df, df$A)
D2 <- lapply(D, newP)
do.call(rbind, D2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out (I assume R is the number of records sorted, so if you have 10 records the last will have R=10)

```
   library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(A=c(1,1,2,2,3),
       R=c(1,2,1,2,1),
       D=c(240,230,305,260,350),
       P=c(300,290,350,290,450))



df %>% group_by(A) %>% 
        mutate(N_P=ifelse(( D<305 & R==n()), # check if D<305 & Record is last record
                          ((305-D)*2)+P      # calculate new P
                          ,P))               # Else : use old P

Source: local data frame [5 x 5]
Groups: A [3]

      A     R     D     P   N_P
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1   240   300   300
2     1     2   230   290   440
3     2     1   305   350   350
4     2     2   260   290   380
5     3     1   350   450   450
```

If you have predefined constants that depend on R value in the df, for example :

```
const <- c(1,2,1.5,2.5,3)
```

You can replace R in the code by `const[R]`

```
df %>% group_by(A) %>% 
    mutate(N_P=ifelse(( D<305 & R==n()), # check if D<305 & Record is last record
                      ((305-D)*const[R])+P      # calculate new P
                      ,P))               # Else : use old P
```

Comment: Thanks! If constant pheno per day will be different for each record class, like first records * 2, second *1,5, third *2,3... Is it possibe to improve this in your code?

Comment: If the constant is dependent on another value like **2*x** where x depends on the record , or if they are limited choices you can predefine them in a vector.

Comment: So what does this factor depends on?

Comment: They was calculated before and they are equal only for one group of record across all animals. As animalls become older, I just can't use one constant for all records. Maximum level for record in data is 5, so i have 5 constants in total.

Comment: If you have 5 constants that depend on R:

Comment: If you have 5 constants that depend on R

`const <- c(1,2,1.5,2.5,3)`

Then you can use the following:

`df %>% group_by(A) %>% 
        mutate(N_P=ifelse(( D<305 & R==n()), # check if D<305 & Record is last record
                          ((305-D)*const[R])+P      # calculate new P
                          ,P))               # Else : use old P`